# Stop Windows 10 from translating appx's based on language setting

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Windows appx's (calculator, photos etc.) seem to translate its names and user interfaces based on the first language in the following language setting: "Settings">"Time & Language">"Language">"Preferred languages".

How do I stop windows from doing this and locking the appx's language to the "Windows display language"?

I'm specifically asking for ways to fix this without the use of group policies, so registry, scripting etc solutions are welcome :)

Comment: Reorder the list?

Comment: This is for use in a larger firm where I need to be able to push the settings via reg changes or script :)   I haven't been able to change the ordering this way, so this time I'm curious if its possible to disable specifically the renaming of the appx's etc